# Same Origin Policy and subdomains

Tags: cross-browser, cors, same-origin-policy

Whether `http://acme.help.com` and `http://acme.com` can be considered as same origin? Will it fall under SO restrictions?

Comment: BTW, I think you mean http://help.acme.com and http://acme.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it will fail. In order for origins to be considered same-origin, their scheme, host and port must match. Here are some examples: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules